# how to search sql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

For the past couple days, I have been trying to learn how to search an mysql database. So far I have the code below. for some reason it isn't searching and giving me results back. my database is named score and the table is all scores. Someone please help me with this.

It should be searching my database but it's coming up with no results. I have made sure everything is correct.

This file is searching.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "score");
    $query = "SELECT `name` FROM `all_scores` WHERE `id` = $id LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $name = $row['name'];
        }
    } else {
        echo "Undifined ID";
        $gameid = "";
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($connect);
} else {
    $gameid = "";
}
```

this is search.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> PHP FIND DATA </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="searching.php" method="post">
        Id:<input type="text" name="id"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Find">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Far as I can see, you never echo'd `$name = $row['name'];`.

Comment: and if by echoing that ^ still doesn't work; check for errors and make sure that `$id` is indeed an integer that's being entered with no whitespace introduced.

Answer (score 2):

To get the form values inside the php file you need to use  [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php). Here's an example using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). You're only retrieving one row so you don't need the while loop.

**searching.php**

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$q = $conn->prepare("SELECT `name` FROM `all_scores` WHERE `id` = :id LIMIT 1");
$q->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
$q->execute();
if ($q->rowCount() > 0) {
    $check = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $row_id = $check['id'];
    // do something
}
```

**Html:**

```
<form action="searching.php" method="post">
Id:<input type="text" name="id"><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Find">
</form>
```

---

Take some time look at [several other examples](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)